# Jenkins Post read a file content and use with archiveArtifacts

Tags: jenkins, groovy

With Jenkins declarative pipeline, I have a file `WORKSPACE/cid`. How do I use its content with `archiveArtifacts`. I tried few things like below and still no luck.
thanks for any help or pointers.

```
post {
        always {
            script {
              echo "Reading content"
              //def filename = readfile('${WORKSPACE}/cid').trim()
            }
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '${filename}/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the filename directly using workspace reference check below example:

```
post {
        always {
            script {
            echo "Reading content"
            //def filename=cat ${WORKSPACE}/cid
            }
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: "${WORKSPACE}/cid"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd like to use `archiveArtifacts` on content of file "${WORKSPACE}/cid". Not on the file itself. For example, "${WORKSPACE}/cid" has content "file1.txt". I need to access and use that. any thoughts on it?

Comment: so you want to archive file1.txt file or the text "file1.txt"?

Comment: if you manage to get full path of file1.txt then you can use that path and archive file1.txt but the file1.txt must be in workspace

Answer (score 0):

Read the content from last stage and used it as `${content}` on `post`

```
content = sh ( script: 'cat ${WORKSPACE}/cid', returnStdout: true).trim()
```